# Changing the login screen language on Windows 8.1 (registry)

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-registry

I'm looking for a way to change the login screen language on Windows 8.1 through the registry. I only need to change that one, not the whole windows language.
I'm talking about this screen:

[image]

I couldn't find any useful info on the net yet. Do you have any idea?

Thanks a lot,

K